# How to make image display as block element when its inside h2 tag

Tags: html, css, layout

I have this html code:

```html
<h2>
  <img align="left" class="left" src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-images/grapefruit-slice-332-332.jpg"> Hello world
</h2>
```

I can't change the HTML but I need the text to be on the next line. I've tried to display block image, but it doesn't work.

The img width should be set to `auto`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the HTML cannot be changed, try flex column

```css
h2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<h2>
  <img align="left" class="left" src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-images/grapefruit-slice-332-332.jpg"> Hello world
</h2>
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply disable the float applied by `align=left`

```css
img {
  display:block;
  float:none;
}
```

```html
<h2>
  <img align="left" class="left" src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-images/grapefruit-slice-332-332.jpg"> Hello world
</h2>
```

With centring:

```css
img {
  display:block;
  float:none;
  margin:auto;
}
h2 {
 text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<h2>
  <img align="left" class="left" src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-images/grapefruit-slice-332-332.jpg"> Hello world
</h2>
```